# How to handle pagination via selenium-webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

My HTML code is look like that.

```
<ul class="pagination"><li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 2" href="/search-property-list?page=1" style="padding: 10px 15px; margin-top: -4px;">2</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 3" href="/search-property-list?page=2">3</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 4" href="/search-property-list?page=3">4</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 5" href="/search-property-list?page=4">5</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 6" href="/search-property-list?page=5">6</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 7" href="/search-property-list?page=6">7</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 8" href="/search-property-list?page=7">8</a></li>
<li><a title="Gå till sida 9" href="/search-property-list?page=8">9</a></li>
<li class="pager-ellipsis disabled"><span>…</span></li>
<li class="next"><a title="Gå till nästa sida" href="/search-property-list?page=1">nästa ›</a></li>
<li class="pager-last"><a title="Gå till sista sidan" href="/search-property-list?page=137">sista ››</a></li>
</ul>
```

My Selenium code is look like that :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);          
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName("a")));
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    String title = elements.get(i).getAttribute("title");
    if (title.equals("Next Page")) {
        elements.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste your html instead of screenshot

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i am not able to move from 1 page to 2 second page.

Comment: Please provide the html code, not text from the page.

Comment: If first WebElement with TagName "a" targets to page 1, click on second one:             elements.get(i + 1).click(); But when trying to reach page 2, the third of elements will be no longer in current DOM, expecting Stale Element Reference Exception.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided it seems you are on *Page 1*. So to browse to the *next page* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li[@class='active']//following::li[1]/a"))).click();
```

Comment: You could also do this by page number: //a[contains(@href, "page=2")] if you wanted to select a specific page and not just the "next" one